# Non blocking cat (Read as much data as you can from stdin and hold it in RAM until a write-blocking stdout becomes available)

Tags: cat, stdout, stdin

I have a program (which may or may not be `aplay`) that accepts its stdin rather slowly.  Programs that write to said stdin (such as via a pipe) tend to block on writes a lot.  Needing to wait on input is unacceptable (as it would cause a break in audio).  said stdin (such as via a pipe) tend to block on writes a lot.  The program that feeds it input can do so rather quickly, but occasionally stutters and stops producing input for a bit every now and then.  Needing to wait on input is unacceptable (as it would cause a break in audio).

Is there a program that reads a bunch of data from stdin and holds it in RAM until stdout writes complete?

Sort of like this Python program I janked together in five minutes, only in C, and not janked together in five minutes:

```py
import threading
import sys
import queue

stdin=sys.stdin.detach().detach() # detach TextIOWrapper, then detach BufferedWriter for a raw input stream.
stdout=sys.stdout.detach()

q=queue.Queue()

def worker(q,stdout):
    while True:
        data=q.get()
        if data is None:
            return
        stdout.write(data)

threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(q,stdout)).start()


data=stdin.read(8192)
while data:
    q.put(data)
    data=stdin.read(8192)
q.put(None)
```

Maybe with features like holding a configurable amount of data in RAM instead of just going until you run out?  Pausing reading input and resuming it when sent SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 perhaps?

Something like this must exist, mustn't it?  It's just that I have no idea what to google.

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/buffer.1.html?

Comment: Your first paragraph seems to say the same thing twice. Are "Programs that write to said stdin" and "The program that feeds it input" referring to the same thing?